# Is it possible to purchase an iPhone app now to download later?

Tags: iphone, applications, ios-appstore

I was wondering if there is a way (or at least if it is possible) to purchase an app from the app store now, but do not download it now (to save on disk space) and download it later when required.

Often there are apps on sale (e.g., Lonely Planet city guides) that are not immediately useful. These are great apps, but not immediately useful. So, instead of downloading the app right away and use up disk space, it would be nice to purchase the app and download later when required.

Comment: Do you mean to save space on your iOS device or your iTunes computer?

Answer (score 7):

You could purchase the app, then tap on the icon as soon as it appears to pause the download, and leave it paused indefinitely.

Comment: I've noticed you wanna give it a second or two first though. You'll know it's paused when it changes from loading to paused.

Answer (score 5):

You can purchase the app through iTunes, rather than the app store.  Then you can download it later.

Comment: This will automatically begin to download the app, just like in iOS. So you will need to go to the downloads tab on the left and pause it as well if you go this route.

Answer (score 3):

You could purchase the app and delete it. When you need it, go back to the appstore and redownload it for free.(since you purchased it already)

Comment: However, this will not have the benefit of saving you from using data on a limited data plan.

Comment: Not entirely sure but I think that this method asks you to 'Buy' again but after clicking the 'Buy' button it will acknowledge that you have already purchased the app.